# How do I replace styled-component "as" property?

Tags: typescript, styled-components

I'm trying to get styled component's `as` property working but it seems to not be letting me pass this (mocked) custom component through.

```
import React from 'react'
import styled, { StyledComponent } from "styled-components"

export interface Props {
  as?: React.ComponentType<any> | undefined;
}

const Color = styled.div`
  color: red
`;

const PageIcon: React.ComponentType<React.HTMLProps<SVGSVGElement>> = '' as unknown as React.ComponentType<React.HTMLProps<SVGSVGElement>>

function Example () {
  return <Color as={PageIcon} /> // fails here
}

const Usage = styled.div`
  ${Color} {
    background-color: black
  }
`;
```

I've tried a bunch of things to be able to override styled's "as" property with no luck.

Comment: This is what the [`css` prop](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#css-prop) is suited for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because styled uses it's component to be used in it's css templating you can't just swap out the type you need to maintain style's type. Here's a way to do this:

```
// hover over your type and copy it into it's own type
type ColorType = StyledComponent<React.FC<Props>, any, {}, never>

// then apply an intersection on the styled type and a plan react component with your custom "as"
const Color: ColorType & React.FC<Props> = styled.div<Props>`
  color: red
`;
```

Here's the run through showing it fail for the other cases where you don't have both `ColorType` and `React.FC<Props>`.

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.7.5#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChRJY4BnGATwBskATAGjgG84Blep5gMK5IAOyQj4AXzjZccAES1GLALRphEMROrzSpJAA9K8YBKRRM6JHAAKOMNU6k4cFNQD8ALkTEYAOiFwTXEYABU6MCQAHhQROgA+OAAfOABXEWYkTFMWAG5SST16SLghBmhwkoBeHj4WQNEQqOR0fwAxASi7CAd49li6dg5JdjEAN3N4vQB6abgAISRygHc4AEk06mtMCFSoOEMUcCZHGAgaAAsIVavV4Hhl6ABrak9SWbgVUr2iCTaUYAMUwAc3ecy+AHkRAw6JUkGDPnAoTCWhgOgivgB1Z4gvQiI5IahgKzfKC-GD-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-vAN6RtGnYYN2QS9kmsZppmOb2WOJbFpO04wDWFkEA2bhpCILZth2YXxiF-ZhUOkU9KOpYTpW1ZTEymALjAS7tqu66bru+4uEeJ5wGeOGXtegF3iID5PnMClvuY8IuF+XlWvA-6AUljosGB7qejBcEIUhcAoWgaEYRk2GuetBGbURHlkYxp1nedF2McxVasWg1jsbGHRcQy+msuynKKsJonCqKfKShI0pyVg8qfcq1CquqmqwFpxT6oayz6Wa36TTae1hR0dlFbWNAgQtmO9E5Xl7X6x3I6GPX+dlPYhKFKYFSO0WlVO5VJfWHbNq2yztqlVPBTTeV0xFDMlbFZUzhVLhVSIi7LvVxzWE1iGQa1UCnnBXW+b1-Wfuaz4g+JI1k1NAERrNuM2YT0GwThCFwGtG1bbsO0uT6+2EZBxFwKR0inddhLEndcDYlATzUkrcDca9-EfUpX3WGJEl-dJAOyfJ+tCWDEPqZE0PaXDem8UjE3WiZqMVJxABkAXtJ0I7Y3N1muvjDmWy7uGHu5JGeV6KOa5TKY5fzkQDoF9NRSL5Ziwl2Ns6lHOZTzA-U4mAuDkL4-jqLzPi3OHyYhCCAANLcHAACEc5SzLdVrvL257uHLVIMeqvterKrdbelra2NhneXA02m0sk6C2S1rZ2lWhRB26EnZYTbnhA6TwjpdxOldPQQA)